# Windows 10 cmd prompt: cannot use German u-Umlaut (ü) in paths, and changing the code page strangely doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, encoding, robocopy, code-page

On my Windows 10 machine I am trying to run a "robocopy" command to backup files.

Everything is fine as long as the paths (to folders to backup) do not contain letters like ö, ü, ä which whoever is inevitable as this is a German environment.

Earlier I was able to fix this by sending a

> ```
> chcp 1252
> ```

command first, so that the command prompt window runs on Code Page 1252 which has these characters. But this was on a Windows 7 machine then.

Now with the Windows 10 machine this does not have effect for me.
The code page is provably set to 1252, and still the `robocopy` command does not run.
(The default code page of this system is 850, by the way.)

> ```
> robocopy C:\Users\Myself\Documents\Notizbücher ^
>   Y:\RobocopyBackups\001_NotizbücherBackup /e /mir /np /z /tee ^
>     /log:Y:\RobocopyBackups\001_Backup_log.txt
> ```

When I run this, the **`"ü"`** always gets messed up, and the command cannot be run since the computer does not find the (messed up) address.

I tried all sorts of things

- Sending first **`chcp 1252`**
- Making sure that my .bat file where I keep the code is encoded as Windows-1252
- Trying **`chcp 65001`** for UTF-8 (with and without encoding the .bat file similarly)
- Trying **`chcp 2851`** for ISO-8859-1, just for fun...

It's always the same: the **`"ü"`** gets messed up.

Of course, I could just remove the **`"ü"`** from the folder names. But I want to have a clean solution, not such a lame workaround.

What could I do?
<sub>**Note: I am using Notepad++**</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Solution found after doing all sorts of experiments:

#### Theory

As the code page used by default on the system is Code Page 850 (part of the "OEM" series of code pages), I decided to give it a try and **save my .bat file with exactly that encoding**.

#### Practice

As I am using Notepad++ for writing, I used Notepad++'s "Encode" option in the menu and selected there

> [Menu] -> Encode --> Character sets --> Western European --> OEM 850

(And of couse I also removed the chcp 1252 command from the batch.)

#### Result

Surprise or not, the system now accepts my batch commands includin German  umlaut characters (ö,ä ü).

#### Note for newbees (like me)

For finding out what the current (default) code page of your system is, enter

```
chcp
```

into your command prompt. It should then return the current value, in my case: 850.